# Screwed up terminal after modifying bashrc

Tags: bashrc

I ended up screwing up my terminal, while setting up Sbt for the Coursera Scala course. I can't summon gedit (or anything else) anymore. I got the following error:

```
Command 'gedit' is available in '/usr/bin/gedit'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
```

Also, each new instance of Terminal writes these messages before any command is written:

```
-bash: :/home/antonio/jdk7/jdk1.7.0_07/bin: No such file or directory
-bash: export: `/home/antonio/Desktop/Scala/install/sbt/bin:/home/antonio/jdk7/jdk1.7.0_07/bin': not a valid identifier
```

I recently did a manual installation of the jdk 7, which apparently works:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

While setting up Sbt, I made the mistake of editing bashrc by writing `gedit  ~/.bashrc` on my terminal instead of writing `gedit .bashrc`, I wrote the following lines at the end of the bashrc file that opened:

```
export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/jdk1.7.0-VERSION/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/home/antonio/jdk7/jdk1.7.0_07/bin:$PATH
```

What is wrong here?

How can I access my bashrc file and modify it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

copy the **.bashrc** from your **/etc/skel** to your home then restart

```
sudo cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/your-user
```

Answer (score 4):

create a new user and copy the .bashrc in its home directory to your home directory

```
sudo cp /home/newuser/.bashrc /home/myuser/
```